# How to use grabWindow to take a screenshot of only a certain region of a window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am currently using the following code to take a screenshot of a window (handle is type HWND):

```
QPixmap::grabWindow((WId) handle).save("haystack.png", "png");
```

However, I only need to take a screenshot of a certain region (rectange) of the window.

In my case, the rectangle has the following vertices:

Top-left corner: (536, 535)

Bottom-right corner: (778, 592)

Answer (score 1):

Right from the documentation:

```
QPixmap QPixmap::grabWindow( WId window,
                             int x = 0,
                             int y = 0,
                             int width = -1,
                             int height = -1 );
```